# How to paginate records from API in Laravel

Tags: php, model, laravel-5

How to paginate/access in any reasonable way remote model based on external API?
For Laravel 4 there's a nice library called Trucker (https://github.com/indatus/trucker), but I've found absolutely no other tool for L5.

The only think I actually care about is how to accomplish code similar to this:

```
$users = UserFromApi::get(); // Get all users from api
$activeUsers = UserFromApi::where('active', 1)->get();
```

...with **UserFromApi** being REMOTE API, not in the database nor anywhere.

I can use simple *get_file_contents()* method, so it's not the request that's problematic, but the approach to do it in Laravel 5, so I can use a model.

Comment: just dont use eloquent... if you got some data from api, than filter the results you want

Comment: If you're remote call dumps data into a "collection" or eloquent model, can't you just ->paginate() the result?  http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/pagination

Comment: @j.steelman my points is *exactly* how am I supposed to dump data into a collection (or preferably even avoid), but still be able to use functions like ->where etc. In CakePHP it's done using datasource and passing it to a model. For complex APIs it can be really big issue. I want to find a proper way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at laravel docs for collections http://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-where

so if you got some data from api, parse it to array and do something like:

```
$collection = collect($data);

$filtered = $collection->where('active', 1);
```

Comment: That is really cool! Thanks, I didn't see it before in the docs. That should do the trick.